# downloaded distribution profile not visible in the code Signing field?

Tags: iphone, distribution, code-signing

i have successfully created distribution profiles and installed on my xcode organiser, but this profile is not visible on my code signing field ?

i tried to upload screenShots, but sorry to say that stackOverflow only allows posting images one who have more than 10 reputations.

please give me a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By code signing field if you mean in build settings, then it is because it is not matching with the bundle identifier of the app. Your identifier maybe `com.something.abc` but your profile maybe created for `com.something.xyz`. Do check on that.

Answer (score 2):

Copy bundle identifier of your  disrtibution profile(com....) and past in bundle idetifier key of your app's info.plist save it.
It will automatically visible your distribution profile.